# Timer making problems in swift Spritekit

Tags: ios, swift, timer

I have created a timer in SpriteKit and put it in the touchesBegan function, but when I touch the screen a second time the result of the timer doubles, I need to write a limit to how many touches can be used to start the timer. Some help would be much appreciated

```
 override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
   for touch: AnyObject in touches {


          var actionrun = SKAction.runBlock({
        self.score++
        self.timesecond++
        if self.timesecond == 60 {self.timesecond = 0}
        self.ScoreLabel.text = "\(self.score/60):0\(self.timesecond)"


          })



    ScoreLabel.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([actionwait,actionrun])))
```

Comment: I think that the timer is just cloning and putting itself in the same scoreLabel when I press the screen a second time.

Comment: You are just repeatedly creating SKActions that do the same thing and telling ScoreLabel to run them. You should probably add a boolean that tells you whether the timer has already started and check before saying runAction.

Comment: That worked, Thanks beyowulf!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the completed solution for anyone who needs it.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
   for touch: AnyObject in touches {




    if ScoreLabel.text == "0:00"{

    let actionrun = SKAction.runBlock({
       self.score++
        self.timesecond++
        if self.timesecond == 60 {self.timesecond = 0}
        self.ScoreLabel.text = "\(self.score/60):0\(self.timesecond)"


          })

   ScoreLabel.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([actionwait,actionrun])))

    }
```